# Send custom SOAP with ExchangeService

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to send a custom SOAP message using ExchangeService. I am not sure if that's possible or not. All I've seen was some OnSerializeCustomSoapHeaders method that was supposed to add a property to every request. But I want to craft the whole message. Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm doing calendar synchronisation from Delphi with custom SOAP requests. Not a small task though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EWS Managed API is open source on https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api you can see the Managed API just uses httpwebRequest under the covers https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/76708b8124cd273b56269334f0a908b2eb0aca6c/Core/EwsHttpWebRequest.cs . Generally the easiest thing to do however is just use httpwebrequest yourself and take the URL etc from the ExchangeService Class you already using (or use httpclient if you want make it async).

Cheers
Glen